# ValueError: invalid __array_struct__ when trying to subclass and initialize ndarray in __new__

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to subclass `np.ndarray` to provide a specialized array containing only `Cell` instances, and with the ability to forward the `getattr` and `setattr` to all the cell contained in the array.

(The `Cell`'s `parent` is an instance of another class that holds the whole, and `Pos` is simply another subclass of `ndarray` with shape always `(2,)`).

However, When trying to instantiate this array, I get this error :

```
  File "models.py", line 91, in __new__
    obj[...] = [ [ Cell(parent, Pos(x, y)) for y in range(h) ] for x in range(w) ]
  File "models.py", line 108, in __setitem__
    return super().__setitem__(k, v)
ValueError: invalid __array_struct__
```

```
class CellGrid(np.ndarray):

  def __new__(
      subtype, shape, dtype=Cell, buffer=None, offset=0,
      strides=None, order=None, parent=None
  ):
    if len(shape) != 2 :
      raise RuntimeError('A grid cannot be other than 2-dimensionnal')
    if not issubclass(dtype, Cell) :
      raise RuntimeError('A grid can only hold Cells')
    obj = super().__new__(
      subtype, shape, dtype,
      buffer, offset, strides, order
    )
    if parent is not None :
      h, w = shape
      obj[...] = [ [ Cell(parent, Pos(x, y)) for y in range(h) ] for x in range(w) ] # ERROR
    return obj

  @classmethod
  def create(cls, shape, parent):
    return cls(shape, parent=parent)

  def __getitem__(self, k):
    if isinstance(k, Pos_t) :
      return super().__getitem__((k[0], k[1]))
    else :
      return super().__getitem__(k)

  def __setitem__(self, k, v):
    if isinstance(k, Pos_t) :
      return super().__setitem__((k[0], k[1]), v)
    else :
      return super().__setitem__(k, v) # ERROR

  def __getattr__(self, k):
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: getattr(x, k), object)(self)

  def __setattr__(self, k, v):
    if k not in self.__dict__ :
      np.frompyfunc(lambda x: setattr(x, k, v), nin=1, nout=0)(self)
```

However, this quite tricky to find information about this "invalid `__array_struct__`" error...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this has nothing to do with subclassing `ndarray`.

It is because I reimplemented `__getattr__` in the `Cell` class, and numpy look for `__array*` attribute in the dtype class, and returning None is invalid for it (it should raise `AttributeError`).

Quick workaround :

start your `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` by short-cutting directly to object if the key start with '__array' :

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
  if(key.startswith('__array'):
    return object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
  # Your code here...

def __getattr__(self, key):
  if(key.startswith('__array'):
    return object.__getattr__(self, key)
  # Your code here...
```

Comment: So how did you solve this? I have the exact same problem: I have a custom `__getattr__`  and also get that same error. I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: Just shortcut it : add at the begin of `__setattr__` : `if key.startswith('__array'): return object.__setattr__(self, key, value)`
(I edited the comment). You also need to do the shortcut for __getattr__ (and __getattribute if you use it) so that it will raise an exception if not present.